# How can i get this JSON value using BeautifulSoup from window.__INITIAL_STATE__

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i am scraping a website containing window.**INITIAL_STATE** which is assigned with a huge JSON string. I am looking for the stock info (This item is currently out of stock) which looks like below in JSON grid:

[image: First level tree]

[image: second level tree]

```
{
    "slotType": "WIDGET",
    "id": 11,
    "parentId": 10002,
    "layoutParams": {
      "margin": "0,24,0,0",
      "orientation": "",
      "widgetHeight": 150,
      "widgetWidth": 12
    },
    "dataId": "1230886539",
    "elementId": "11-AVAILABILITY",
    "hasWidgetDataChanged": true,
    "ttl": 3000,
    "widget": {
      "type": "AVAILABILITY",
      "viewType": "brand",
      "data": {
        "announcementComponent": {
          "action": null,
          "metaData": null,
          "tracking": null,
          "trackingData": null,
          "value": {
            "type": "AnnouncementValue",
            "subTitle": "This item is currently out of stock",
            "title": "Sold Out"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I tried like below but does not work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
print(soup.find(elementID='11-AVAILABILITY').get_text().strip())
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely url is: https://www.flipkart.com/sony-310ap-wired-headset/p/itm0527f8b27c68f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse the `__INITIAL_STATE__` out of HTML, you can use this example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/sony-310ap-wired-headset/p/itm0527f8b27c68f'
html_data = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r'window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ({.*});', html_data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for w in data['pageDataV4']['page']['data']['10002']:
    if w.get("elementId") == "11-AVAILABILITY":
        print(json.dumps(w, indent=4))
        break
```

Prints:

```
{
    "slotType": "WIDGET",
    "id": 11,
    "parentId": 10002,
    "layoutParams": {
        "margin": "0,24,0,0",
        "orientation": "",
        "widgetHeight": 150,
        "widgetWidth": 12
    },
    "dataId": "1230886539",
    "elementId": "11-AVAILABILITY",
    "hasWidgetDataChanged": true,
    "ttl": 3000,
    "widget": {
        "type": "AVAILABILITY",
        "viewType": "brand",
        "data": {
            "announcementComponent": {
                "action": null,
                "metaData": null,
                "tracking": null,
                "trackingData": null,
                "value": {
                    "type": "AnnouncementValue",
                    "subTitle": "This item is currently out of stock",
                    "title": "Sold Out"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```